# Intuitive understanding of Bezout's Identity?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, intuition, gcd-and-lcm

Bézout's identity — Let $a$ and $b$ be integers with greatest common divisor $d$. Then there exist integers $x$ and $y$ such that $ax + by = d$. More generally, the integers of the form $ax + by$ are exactly the multiples of $d$.

---

Proof from Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_identity
[image]

---

The proof is simple enough, but I was just wondering if anyone had anything more to say about why this theorem is to be expected. Why is a linear combination of two natural numbers a multiple of their greatest common divisor? Can this be understood in terms of the prime factorizations of the two natural numbers? Thank you.

Comment: In a sense, it cannot be completely understood in terms of the prime factorizations because it holds in contexts where unique factorization fails. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bézout_domain

Comment: For getting a "feel" of what's going on, as opposed to a proof, have you played with the [Euclidean Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm)? I really like the picture with the two sticks that's at the top of that article.